# Add multiple dynamic attachments to email

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm listing all PDF files of a folder and send them into an email.
The issue is that I don't know how attach multiple files.

This is what I've tried so far: put files into blob then pass it.
Other try was to put blob[0] and blob[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehR9r.png) if there is 2 pdf files but it doesn't work.

```
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderToScan);
  var folder = folders.next();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();

  var blob = [];
  var filesTextList = "";

  // foreach file
  for(var counter = 0;contents.hasNext();counter++)
  {
    file = contents.next();

    var MimeType = file.getMimeType();

    // filter PDF
    if(file.getMimeType() == "application/pdf")
       {
         blob[counter] = file.getBlob();
         // add file name to text
         filesTextList += "\n" + file.getName();
    }
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(sender, subject, message, 
   {attachments: blob}
);
```

If I only have 1 blob file, {attachments: blob[0]} is working but it's not dynamic

Here is the debugger at the line of the mail:
[image: debugger]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attachments` parameter of [sendEmail method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage) takes "an array of files to send with the email". They can be File objects, you don't have to get blobs from them.

More importantly, your loop will create an array with undefined elements because `blob[counter]` only gets assigned when the file is a PDF, but the value of `counter` increases regardless.  I don't think sendEmail will be happy about that.

Use `while` loop with iterators, and `push` method to add elements to an array. A complete example.

```
function emailatt() {
  var contents = DriveApp.getFolderById("id here").getFiles();
  var attachments = [];
  while (contents.hasNext()) {
    var file = contents.next();
    if (file.getMimeType() == "application/pdf") {
      attachments.push(file);
    }
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail("user@example.com", "subject", "body", {attachments: attachments});
}
```

Aside: getting folder by Id is best when you know what folder you want. Using `getFoldersByName` and then picking whatever folder with that name came up first is a less robust approach.

Comment: Clear as water. I had 1 file that wasn't PDF so one element has no blob as you said. So for isn't requested as you said. Thanks!!!